# Converting xml to string and back again produces 'root element error'

Tags: c#, xml

I'm converting an "unusual" xml to a string.  I say unusual as i'm using the .NET ChartSerializer to save winforms chart state:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    chart1.Serializer.Save(ms);
    xml.Load(ms);
}
```

if i convert to a string using

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
     using (XmlTextWriter txt = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
     {
         xml.WriteTo(txt);
         string str = sw.ToString();
         fuse.c1 = str;
     }
}
```

and save it to a file (i've tried JSON, txt, xml), then convert back using

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(fuse.c1);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    xml.Save(ms);
    chart1.Serializer.Load(ms);
}
```

i get an error `root element is missing`

i don't understand the error, as i'm simply converting to a string and back again using the same classes etc.

i'm not very familiar with xml, can anyone spot my misstep?  I'm trying to save multiple winforms charts without an .xml file for each chart

sample xml:

```
<Chart Size="854, 215">
  <Series>
    <Series Name="Series1" Legend="Legend1" ChartArea="ChartArea1" Color="Orange" LegendText="% Change">
      <Points>
        <DataPoint YValues="10.3973534917773" />
        <DataPoint XValue="0.2" YValues="8.37818721941151" />
        <DataPoint XValue="0.4" YValues="5.57375277883594" />
**snip many more data points**
     </Points>
    </Series>
  </Series>      
  <ChartAreas>
    <ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
    </ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
</Chart>
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to save multiple winforms charts without an .xml file for each chart"* Does it work for a single chart? Did you already look into the generated files?

Comment: Can you send the sample of the created xml file?

Comment: if i just use the serializer.Save() then i get an .xml file, and i can indeed load it back into the chart control (the .xml file that is, not a string and back).  if i can get it to work with one, i will make a string[] for all the charts.

Comment: Try `ms.Position = 0` between the `xml.Save(ms)` and the `chart1.Serializer.Load(ms)` calls. Stream operations quite often leave the stream "cursor" at the end.

Comment: Use XElement.Load instead and see if that helps. You are missing the xml element on the sample that you provided, normal xml starts with the xml element as the first element.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis it has worked for a single file!  shows how much i know about xml.  i can't thank you enough, now i will try with my array.  thanks so much i spent a lot of time on this.

Comment: @mahlatse that is how the file is created with the Serializer.  i will try your method as well, and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer to your *specific* question in the comments - you need to rewind the stream.

But it's worth noting that there seems to be [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) that accept `TextWriter` and `TextReader`, so you can do what you're doing with much less ceremony.

To save, you can use a `StringWriter`:

```
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    chart1.Serializer.Save(writer);
    fuse.c1 = writer.ToString();
}
```

And to load it back again, you can use a `StringReader`:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(fuse.c1))
{
    chart1.Serializer.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, i now have a new tool in the box, and simpler code.  works good